# Double submit a value form in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, iframe

i want to double submit a value form in frame look like this code.

**index.php**

```
<form action="iframe1.php" method="post" target="iframe1">
<input type="text" name="lala">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe name="iframe1" src="iframe1.php"></iframe>
```

**iframe1.php**

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="lili" value="'.$_POST['lala'].'"></button>
</form>
```

**foo.php**

```
<?php echo $_POST'lili']; ?>
```

with above code it success to submit a value from ***index.php*** to ***iframe1.php*** but ***iframe1.php*** not submit it to ***foo.php***. it stop to ***iframe1.php***. so how to make ***iframe1.php*** submit when value is not empty else do nothing if value is empty.

Comment: Why would the form auto submit? I guess I have no idea what you are asking other than sounds like you need validation.

Comment: yeah, it's same like validation if value empty do nothing else submit.  you know how to this with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of javascript in iframe1.php is required to do auto submit.

index.php

```
<form action="iframe1.php" method="post" target="iframe1">
<input type="text" name="lala">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1" src="iframe1.php"></iframe>
```

iframe1.php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['lala'])):?>
<form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form2">
<input type="hidden" name="lili" value="<?php echo $_POST['lala']; ?>" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form2').submit();
</script>
<?php else:?>
    <div>Nonthing posted</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

foo.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['lili']; ?>
```

Comment: Its working fine if you could use the above code.. I've changed few things which had syntax errors